# How to fix my root filesystem being full?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I've recently just installed Ubuntu 16 as a dualboot with Windows 10. I gave the partion around 20Gb when asked during the  install process. I haven't really used it all that much yet now I can't download or even do some basic commands as there is no space available.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  9.5M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda6       5.8G  5.8G     0 100% /
tmpfs           7.8G   21M  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda8       9.8G  1.1G  8.3G  11% /home
/dev/sda1       256M   51M  206M  20% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G   64K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda3       209G  113G   97G  54% /media/myfullname/TIH0435382
```

I see that my "/" directory is full but I'm just wondering why it is so small relative to the amount assigned and how that works given my "/home" is relatively empty in comparison. Can I change it to use my /home directory for downloads?

If anyone could help me fix this it  would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Lately? Is it possible you are holding on to outdated kernel updates?